# Laravel + Flatpickr: How to Preload Date for Today and Tomorrow

Tags: laravel, flatpickr

Newbie here. I'm trying to preload dates for the Flatpickr for Today and Tomorrow but don't know how to:

index.blade.php

```php
{{-- Preload Date Today --}}
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="loaned">Loaned</label>
  <input defaulDate="minDate:Today" type="date" class="form-control" name="loaned" id="loaned" >
</div>

{{-- Preload Date Tomorrow--}}
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="due">Due</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="due" id="due" value="">
</div>



@section('scripts')
<script>
    flatpickr('#loaned');
    flatpickr('#due');
</script>
@endsection
```

I saw this in the documentation `https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#preloading-a-date`, but they did not show how to use it:

```
{
    minDate: "today",
    maxDate: new Date().fp_incr(14) // 14 days from now
}
```

Updated 2020.09.20: Thanks to apokryfos for Solution.

```php
@section('scripts')
  <script>
    flatpickr('#loaned', {
        defaultDate: 'today',

    });
    flatpickr('#due', {
        defaultDate: new Date().fp_incr(1),
    });
  </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Try `flatpckr('#loaned', { minDate: "today" })` I agree the documentation is not super clear about this but this is how I'd expect it to be

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you for responding. I tried what you suggested and I get no errors. However, the datepicker is still blank.

Comment: If you mean that there's no value in the input then you need to provide it via `value=...` check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9ym3efd/). Clicking on the input shows the flatpicker popup in both cases

Comment: Ok thanks. How do we put `today` in value=" ". So that when the page is clicked, the flatpickr automatically displays today.

Comment: O I found it! Thanks! You're a genius. Any chance I can get your email? Or is there a way to DM you here?

Comment: If you really need to then you can probably use [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms) and make a room to invite me in. But outside of weekends my free time is very limited